# Jetty deployment: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: jetty, cdi, war, weld

I tried to deploy to and run Jetty from an Ant-script, but get the following error:

```
[jetty.run] 2016-06-25 09:16:54.333: Starting web application null
[jetty.run] [main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter - 
[jetty.run] javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, WebSocket+CDI support unavailable
[jetty.run]     at org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.websocket.WebSocketCdiInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketCdiInitializer.java:49)
[jetty.run]     at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
[jetty.run]     at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
[jetty.run]     at 
...
```

It work without deployment, but with the war-file this happens. What is corrupt?

UPDATE:

Added

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <resource-env-ref>
    <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
```

to web.xml andweld jars to lib. Now I get this:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[jetty.run]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[jetty.run]     at      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[jetty.run]     at ...
[jetty.run] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name BeanManager
```

UPDATE 2:

Ok, I didn't need the extra things in my web.xml. Instead I had forgot to add

```
<typedef name="webApp" classname="org.eclipse.jetty.ant.AntWebAppContext" classpathref="classpath" loaderref="jetty.loader"/>
```

to build.xml. I can now deploy and run jetty, but can't process JSP files:

```
[jetty.run] [qtp1387380406-14] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - 
[jetty.run] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
[jetty.run]     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600) ...
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the various jetty cdi jar files from your project.

Those are designed specifically for `jetty-distribution` use, and are inappropriate for `embedded-jetty`.

Use the weld jars directly in your war file, along with the various recommended configurations that [the weld project documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty) tell you about.

Comment: Added the weld jars and the listener in my web.xml. Now I  get this:     org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name BeanManager

Comment: Im I using embeeded-jetty with Ant??